# woocommerce with custom post type

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I create new post type suppose "custom_type" and i want to use that post type with Woocommerce function. so Woocommerce will work with "product and custom_type".

i searched everywhere and don't find any answer also i have found how to customize current post type names etc but i want both post type.

so both post type will work and user can checkout at same place.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll be able to pull this off directly. All of the admin screens, objects and hooks are tied to the "product" post type.

What you should probably do is add a new product type (a sister to the simple/variable product types). This new product type could be called "Custom_Type". You can then add a field that lets you point to one of your custom post type objects.

This is a workaround. It means for every "custom type" you would also have a "custom type product" which references it. It's not pretty, but it might work.

Answer (score 1):

This page describe how to do this manually: [How to add custom post type to WooCommerce](https://reigelgallarde.me/programming/how-to-add-custom-post-type-to-woocommerce/).

This is from the maker of the WooRei Shop Manager plugin, that also explain (for free) how to do it without his plugin.

Answer (score 1):

@MamunurRashid **[Custom Post Type WooCommerce Integration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cpt-woo-integration/)** Really Awesome plugin.

I had been looking for solutions like this, and your comment was the one that truly helped me find what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

The following (free) plugin is exactly what you need: [WooCommerce WooRei Shop Manager](http://reigelgallarde.me/product/woocommerce-woorei-shop-manager/)

> This plugin extends the WooCommerce e-commerce plugin by allowing a
>   custom post type (CPT) to be added.

Comment: downvoted as the plugin is not free and  "buy a plugin" is not a useful answer here

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress ORG has a plugin name is
["Custom Post Type WooCommerce Integration"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cpt-woo-integration/)

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cpt-woo-integration/